# D3DXLoadSurfaceFromFile causes program to close prematurely

Tags: c++, directx

I'm new to DirectX and C++ programming, but need to for a homework assignment (I've already completed the actual assignment but can't get my code to run post-compile). I've stepped into my program and have found the problem to be my `D3DXLoadSurfaceFromFile` call. The actual code is

```
//load m_Surface from file into newly created m_Surface
result = D3DXLoadSurfaceFromFile(
    m_Surface,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    m_BackgroundFile,
    NULL,   
    D3DX_DEFAULT,
    0,  
    NULL);
```

Where 'result' is:

```
    HRESULT result = m_d3ddev->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(
    SCREENW,            //An int set to 640
    SCREENH,            //An int set to 480
    D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8,    //m_Surface's format
    D3DPOOL_DEFAULT,    //Memory pool
    &m_Surface,         //Pointer to m_Surface
    NULL);              //Reserved
```

`m_Surface` is an `LPDIRECT3DSURFACE9` initially set to `NULL`.

`m_BackgroundFile` is set to "filename.bmp" (a 24-bit bitmap)

and (I think/hope) everything else is self-explanatory.

If it helps, right before I check (which is the check that causes the program to close)

```
if (!SUCCEEDED(result))
    return false;
```

result is set to S_OK, and then -200559767

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, I didn't see anything wrong, but I guess you pass in a wrong file to parameter m_BackgroundFile, either the program can not find the file or the file was not in a acceptable format.